# Create new file only if it cannot be opened and read in Python using "with __ as"

Tags: python, io

I would like to try opening a file to read, and only if this fails, overwrite it or create a new file. I know it can be done using try, except, finally methodology, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to do it with the `with` & `as` keywords.

```py
try: 
   f = file.open("file","r")
   try:
       parse_file(f)
   finally:
       f.close()
except CustomError as e:
    overwrite_file(e)
except FileNotFoundError:
    create_file()
except:
    handle_errors()
```

Comment: Put the code that opens or creates the file in a function, and call that to open the file.

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want to do. Do you actually want to read anything from the file before overwriting it?

Comment: One way you might be able to make this concept clearer is to provide a [mcve] that uses try/except/finally methodology to carry out the desired behavior. Then we can be sure that our answers match that behavior, since we'll be able to test it ourselves.

Comment: @Kevin attempted to provide a code example

Comment: Do `overwrite_file` and `create_file` ultimately put the same data into the file? Perhaps you could simplify those by making them into a single function.

Comment: overwrite_file would conditionally add different information to the file based on properties set in the CustomError thrown to it, possibly tracking the cause of the CustomError if it occurred through parsing the data.